# How to rename the wall command in AWS Linux?

Tags: linux, shell, alias

I am writing a wrapper shell script with the name "`wall`" which resides in e.g. `/usr/bin`. It would inspect the user id and refuse to call the actual wall command (which should be renamed) unless the ID matches root.

How do I rename the wall command in the script?

I've tried `$/usr/bin` but it gave an error. I also tried `-d /usr/bin` but it didn't work out as well.

Here is the script:

```
if [[ $UID == 0 ]]; 
then 
    <renamed wall> "$@"; 
else 
    echo "Only root can write in the wall" >&2; 
fi
```

Comment: and any feedback on why this would work/wouldn't work?

Answer (score 0):

Would recommend you just change the permissions on the `wall` binary instead. e.g. `chmod 700 /usr/bin/wall`